# System interface becomes blurry, looks out of focus after system crash

Tags: gnome, display, visual-artifacts

The whole system suddenly restarted when I was watching video. After rebooting, the display has become blurred and out of focus. The interface becomes normal for around 2 seconds whenever that window is moved or active.

I had this problem when I used Ubuntu from the first time. It was solved by installing Gnome.

What causes the interface blur and how could I i fix it? The video card that I am using is from Nvidia, I don't know whether this relates to the problem or not.

I also suspect the Gnome is not working after the system crash. Can anyone explain how to check whether Gnome is working or not? And how to repair it?

Answer (score 9):

If you're using an Nvidia card go to Nvidia settings (from terminal: nvidia-settings ) and then in X Screen -> Antialiasing Settings uncheck "Enable FXAA". After restarting gnome it should work correctly.

Comment: Still valid for the latest drivers and Ubuntu 18.04.